# This C code is supposed to fail but it works. Why is that?

Tags: c, gcc

Folks I think I will throw all my modest C lore away. Look at this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)
{
  int aa;

  srand(time(NULL));

  int Num = rand()%20;

  int Vetor[Num];

  for (aa = 0; aa < Num; aa++)
  {
    Vetor[aa] = rand()%40;
    printf("Vetor [%d] = %d\n", aa, Vetor[aa]);
  }
}
```

I would think that this should throw an error for two reasons - first that I am declaring both Num and Vetor after executing a command (srand), second because I am declaring Vetor based on Num, this should not be possible right? because those array sizes should not be decided at runtime but at compile time right?

I am really surprised that his works and if you guys could explain why I can actually use stuff like this would be great.

This is using GCC.

Comment: What did you use to compile this? If you compiled it with something that also compiles C++, it may have simply said "oh, it's legit because C++ says it's so".

Comment: @TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars but it is not legit C++.

Comment: @phresnel and what makes it not C++?

Comment: @TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars [the question] because the questioner writes "C" and uses the C-tag. [the code] because it uses variable length arrays, which are a feature of C, but not of C++

Comment: @phresnel there are few features (so few you might as well call it none) of C that are not valid in C++. By virtue of that, it is valid C++ as well as valid C.

Comment: @TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars: No. C++ does not have any notion of variable length arrays. You can only have arrays of compile-time-fixed length.

Comment: @TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars If you look at the wikipedia page for C99, you'll discover many more features of C that are not valid C++, most notably named initializers, variadic macros, restrict pointers, long long integers, extended math functions in the standard library, and more. C++'s support for C is based on C89, i.e. C++ support, last standard was released 2003,  is more than a decade behind the current C standard.

Comment: @phresnel I can go along with that. I wasn't aware C++ hadn't kept up with C support.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are C99 features, and it seems your compiler supports them. That's all ;)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99):

> C99 introduced several new features, many of which had already been implemented as extensions in several compilers:
>
> - inline functions
> - **intermingled declarations and code, variable declaration no longer
>     restricted to file scope or the start
>     of a compound statement (block)**
> - several new data types, including long long int, optional extended
>     integer types, an explicit boolean
>     data type, and a complex type to
>     represent complex numbers
> - **variable-length arrays**
> - support for one-line comments beginning with //, as in BCPL or C++
> - new library functions, such as snprintf
> - etc ([more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Design))

Comment: Oh! living and learning! better read the spec on C99, thanks for the answer

Comment: Yup, even `sizeof` must tell you the size of the variable-length array, so it is no longer just a compile-time thing, it must have a runtime implementation also.

Answer (score 1):

C99 supports declarations anywhere in the code, as well as VLAs. What compiler are you using?

Comment: thanks for the tip. This is GCC, just learned about C99 will catch up with the standards.